# How to style a Textbox's Scrollbar to match the website's scrollbar?

Tags: html, css, scroll, webkit, scrollbar

So, I've successfully gotten the scrollbar I've wanted just fine, but for whatever reason--whether it be the coding has changed since I last tried to do this or being sick has made me forget the proper way to do so--I can not manage to get the scrollbar for the textboxes to match.

Right now, it ends up looking like this and it just... does not look great:
[image: Textbox Scrollbar and Site Scrollbar]

Current CSS:

```
.textbox {scrollbar-face-color: #29FDF1;
scrollbar-shadow-color: #080C0D;
scrollbar-highlight-color: #29FDF1;
scrollbar-3dlight-color: #29FDF1;
scrollbar-darkshadow-color: #080C0D;
scrollbar-track-color: #080C0D;
scrollbar-arrow-color: #29FDF1;}

body::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 7px;
    background-color: #081114;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #081114;
  border: 1px solid #29FDF1;
}
```

Current HTML for the text box:

```
<div class="textbox" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; overflow:auto;">
TEXT HERE
</div>
```

Comment: Your textbox css should be a class not id

Comment: @BlessingOni I thought it was a class?

Comment: Your css code is targeting an id of "#textbox" instead of ".textbox"

Comment: @BlessingOni Ugh, darn it, thank you. Unfortunately, despite fixing that, it seems to still not have changed in any way :(

Comment: did you try my answer below?

Comment: Yep! I was just responding to it, actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`enter code here`Try adding the class of the textbox also. Like this. Hope this helps

```css
.textbox {scrollbar-face-color: #29FDF1;
    scrollbar-shadow-color: #080C0D;
    scrollbar-highlight-color: #29FDF1;
    scrollbar-3dlight-color: #29FDF1;
    scrollbar-darkshadow-color: #080C0D;
    scrollbar-track-color: #080C0D;
    scrollbar-arrow-color: #29FDF1;}
    
    body::-webkit-scrollbar,.textbox::-webkit-scrollbar {
        width: 7px;
    }
    
    body::-webkit-scrollbar-track, .textbox::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    }
    
    body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb, .textbox::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
      background-color: #081114;
      border: 1px solid #29FDF1;
    }
```

```html
<div class="textbox" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; overflow:auto;">
TEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERE
</div>
```

Comment: Updated with this :) But unfortunately no change in appearance :(

Comment: You have to put more text in it so it overflows. then you can see the scroll effect

Comment: I know! It has enough text in it for the overflow actually (I just made the font color the same color as background because it's all gibberish). That said, using your recent edit it seemed to work? So Thank you!